# wp_get_archives: Put span inside anchor tags

Tags: wp-get-archives

I know how it is possible to wrap HTML around anchor elements with the inbuilt arguments for `wp_get_archives`. Is there a way to alter the content of the anchors in order to add a wrapping span for the anchor text? 
The intention is to use it for a list of yearly archives on a category (i.e. an automated list of years for which posts exist).

Before:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="xx">2014</a></li>
    <li><a href="xx">2015</a></li>
    <li><a href="xx">2016</a></li>
</ul>
```

After:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="xx"><span>2014</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="xx"><span>2015</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="xx"><span>2016</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Span outside anchor tags

I think you're looking for the `before` and `after` arguments (*PHP 5.4+*):

```
wp_get_archives(
    [
        'before' => '<span>',
        'after'  => '</span>'
    ]
);
```

if you want to wrap the `<span>` tag around the `<a>` tag:

```
<li><span><a href="xx">Link text</a></span></li>
```

### Span inside anchor tags

If you want it inside the anchor tags:

```
<li><a href="xx"><span>Link text</span></a></li>
```

then you could use the `get_archives_link` filter to reconstruct the links to your needs.

Modify the corresponding theme file with (*PHP 5.4+*):

```
// Add a custom filter
add_filter( 'get_archives_link', 'wpse_get_archives_link', 10, 6 );

// Archive
wp_get_archives(
    [
        'type'   => 'yearly', // For yearly archive
        'format' => 'html'    // This is actually a default setting
    ]
);  // EDIT the arguments to your needs (I'm not showing the <ul> part here)

// Remove the custom filter
remove_filter( 'get_archives_link', 'wpse_get_archives_link', 10, 6 );
```

where our filter callback is defined, in the `functions.php` file in the current theme directory, as:

```
function wpse_get_archives_link(  $link_html, $url, $text, $format, $before, $after )
{
    if( 'html' === $format )
         $link_html = "\t<li>$before<a href='$url'><span>$text</span></a>$after</li>\n";

    return $link_html;
}
```

where we've added the span inside the anchor tag.

Comment: Thanks a lot so far, the second option is close to what I intended. However, two problems, possibly the first on my account: 1) When using `get_archives_link` in my template then puts the links out of context, possibly because of returning in the filter? 2) With get_archives_link I cannot have automatic YEARLY archive links, can I? The codex doesn't specify it is possible at all.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by context and automatic here. Are you using the `get_archives_link()` function directly in your theme? You want to modify the `wp_get_archives()` only via filters from a plugin and not modify the theme? Can you give an example in your question? thanks @physalis

Comment: Hey @birgire, I was about to use `wp_get_archives` on a category archive page in order to have a list of clickable yearly archives within that archive. With its parameters, I can use `wp_get_archives` to do exactly that, but it is not possible to change the output of the text inside the anchor, so I could simply wrap a span around it :). As far as I understand, `get_archives_link` is meant to retrieve one specific archive link, at least not yearly archives? And yes, I tried to use `get_archives_link` within my template, but its output returned at the top of the source code.

Comment: NOW I got it. Your complete first block of code goes into the actual template, while the filter callback alone needs to go into my functions.php. This way, I can still use `wp_get_archives` with all parameters needed. I totally didn't get this point, and I thought I had to fiddle with the get_archives_link function! Can you please edit it to clarify, so I can mark your answer as right? Thanks again for your help!!

Comment: You're welcome - glad to hear you got this working. Yes that was the setup I had in mind, sorry if that wasn't clear from the beginning. I updated the answer. @physalis

Comment: Perfect, @birgire, thank you so much! It was a small bit I wasn't aware of, so thanks a bunch & hope it will help others hunting the same thing :).

Answer (score -1):

You can use custom query to modify html or add span

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) posts, YEAR(post_date) y, MONTH(post_date) m 
    FROM $wpdb->posts 
   WHERE post_status = 'publish'
GROUP BY y, m
  HAVING y = YEAR(NOW())
UNION
  SELECT COUNT(ID), YEAR(post_date) y, 0
    FROM $wpdb->posts
   WHERE post_status = 'publish'
GROUP BY y
  HAVING y < YEAR(NOW())
ORDER BY y DESC, m DESC;
```

Comment: Can you explain how it helps, afaik you are giving raw SQL here.